# How to capture metrics for REST end points via micrometer libraray

Tags: spring, micrometer

I am working on component that is based on spring framework. We have not yet moved to spring boot.

My requirement is to capture metrics(JVM/http/disk space) for my component which runs on an application server.

I came across micrometer library which can be utilized to capture such metrics and it can be integrated very well with Promotheus.
What I did was that I added the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding the dependency I exposed a rest end point and added some simple logic to pull the metrics. Doing that I was able to fetch some basic JVM metrics. I referred the below link for this which explains how to capture metrics.

(https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/jvm)

However in addition to JVM metrics I also want to capture http request metrics(eg. the no of requests, time taken on the http calls to the rest services).

In my application there are quite many rest endpoints. Is there any way to do that. I was not able find any good documentation on that.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Sachin

Comment: Can you please call out your specific question? Are you trying to expose the Prometheus metrics endpoint for scraping or trying to figure out how to measure a rest endpoint? Try to keep your question focused on a single topic. (and post more questions later focused on the further points)

Comment: First of all thanks for replying.I will try to be more specific.I need to understand how do measure rest end point statistics eg. no of requests,time taken for requests.I saw similar such things provided by Spring boot actuator.Is that possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Spring Boot does this out of the box so if you can move there, you don't need to do anything.

In order to instrument your web endpoints you can do a few things:

1. You can create a `Filter` and instrument all of your calls there.
   This is what Spring Boot does, you can take a look/copy [`WebMvcMetricsFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsFilter.java)
2. You can add `@Timer` for your controllers and set-up `TimedAspect`
3. You can manually instrument your controllers see the [docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers)

Comment: Yes spring boot is the thing which we need to update to and that is the best way to achieve it but, meanwhile I will have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

After following the above suggestions I was actually able to see my http metrics

I Simply created a configuration class annotated with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy and defined a bean inside the class as below

```
@Bean
public TimedAspect timedAspect() {
   return new TimedAspect(registry);
}
```

And then added the @Timed annotation on my REST api POST methods and then I was able to see the statistics in Prometheus dashboard.

This really works!